# Ascending Sort in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to fetch Objects in Ascending order from core data. The problem is, I want the objects as

```
Abc ,abc Ball, ball bat, Cat, can
```

But, it sends like,

```
Abc,Ball,Cat ,abc, ball, cat
```

Following is my code.

```
class func CD_FetchAllContacts()->[RecentContact]{
    var arrResult:[RecentContact] = []
    let managedContext = PM.instance().managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "RecentContact")
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare))]
    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext?.fetch(fetchRequest)
        arrResult = results as! [RecentContact]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    print(arrResult.count)
     return arrResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort descriptor should be like this, with `(_ :)` at the end:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))]
```

Edit: Actually even with your version of the sort descriptor it's working on a test project I've done. Nothing seems wrong with the code posted. Are you sorting the returned array in other part of your code?